# c++ localtime when changing timezone

Tags: c++, localtime

I have a setup working using localtime()  to get a tm with the local times represented in it.  And that is all good.

However, if I change timezone while the application is running, it does not notice that I have changed timezones.

Is there some way to tell it to 'go look again'  to refresh to the system timezone?

I know this is probably not a common case, but it is what test are doing to test this feature, so they want it supported!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library to do this. Unless your platform offers some extension to the library for updating the time zone, your program's calls to `localtime()` will probably always use the time zone that was active at program start up.

You could probably work around that by putting the `localtime` stuff in a separate process that your main program can startup and shutdown at will, thus re-initializing that process's time zone.

Or instead your platform may offer some other API for getting the local time that will reflect changes in the system time zone.

Comment: I feared (or maybe hoped!)  it would be something like that.  We have hopes of being cross platform later, so Posix solution isn't good.  Will have to go with a documentation 'if you change time zones, restart service' solution.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `tzset` (this is posix only). This might give you what you need. If your `TZ` environment variable is unset, it should reinitialize from the OS.

From the man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  tzset()  function initializes the tzname variable from the TZ environment variable.  This function is automatically called by the
>   other time conversion functions that depend on the time zone.  In a
>   SysV-like environment it will  also  set  the  variables  timezone
>   (seconds  West  of  GMT)  and daylight (0 if this time zone does not
>   have any daylight savings time rules, non-zero if there is a time
>   during the year when daylight savings time applies).
>
> If the TZ variable does not appear in the environment, the tzname variable is initialized with the best approximation  of  local 
>   wall clock  time,  as specified by the tzfile(5)-format file localtime
>   found in the system timezone directory (see below).  (One also often
>   sees /etc/localtime used here, a symlink to the right file in the
>   system timezone directory.)

A simple test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        tzset();

        time_t t;
        time(&t);

        std::cout << "tz: " << tzname[0] << " - " << tzname[1] << " " << ctime(&t) << std::endl;

        setenv("TZ", "EST5EDT", 1);
        tzset();

        std::cout << "tz: " << tzname[0] << " - " << tzname[1] << " " << ctime(&t) << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Gives me output:

> tz: CST - CDT Wed Jan 11 12:35:02 2012
>
> tz: EST - EDT Wed Jan 11 13:35:02 2012

Comment: Unfortunately we hope to be cross platform, so posix solution isn't going to cut it.  But thanks!