# printout time in a specified timezone

Tags: c

I can printout time in UTC and local time like this:

```
  time_t now;
  struct tm  ts, tm;
  char buf[80];
  now = time(NULL);
  ts = *gmtime(&now);
  tm = *localtime(&now);
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &tm);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
```

But how do I printout time in a specified timezone that is different than UTC or my current timezone? Also, would it be OS/distro dependent?

Comment: Not by "pure C". Pretty sure that it is possible with POSIX (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824156/c-localtime-when-changing-timezone)), which means that it is OS-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the nuance. It seems I can use the provided answer for my case but it is good to know its limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the approach documented here [How can I set the time zone before calling strftime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620188/how-can-i-set-the-time-zone-before-calling-strftime), so use `setenv` and `tzset` before calling strftime:

```
setenv("TZ", "PST8PDT", 1);
tzset();
mtt = time(NULL);
mt = localtime(&mtt);
strftime(ftime,sizeof(ftime),"%Z %H%M",mt);
```